# HSSFWorkbook is imported, XSSFWorkbook is not, why? Apache Poi 5.0.0

Tags: java, apache-poi, openxml

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtrVT.png) HSSFWorkbook is imported, XSSFWorkbook is not, why? I make an application with reading .xls and .xlsx files with Apache poi 5.0.0. Here are my [imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihof2.png). Here are my [build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Sgr9.png). Maybe I need to connect multidex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the OOXML schema. Add the following to your build.gradle dependencies (additionally to the already existing org.apache.poi.poi dependency):

```
implementation: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '5.0.0'
```